# Как скрыть код программы?

Tags: windows, обфускация

Здравствуйте!

Как можно скрыть код программы от сигнатурного анализа антивирусов? Если, например, повторно переупаковать файл программы PE-пакером UPX, то изменится ли при этом внутреннее представление кода?

Answer (score 3):

Как только код загружен в память, он может быть проанализирован. Упаковщик UPX добавляет в исполняемый файл свой загрузчик, и архивирует бинарник. При запуске загрузчик распаковывает бинарник, код грузится в память и ему передается управление. После этого код доступен для анализа. Сама схема защиты от анализа (разбиение кода на части) может быть анализируемой сигнатурой.

Comment: Спасибо. Полезная информация. А какие схемы защиты от сигнатурного анализа могут быть применены?

Comment: Основной подход - это изобретение и внедрение новых, неизвестных антивирусам сигнатур.

Comment: Хех, ну это очень сложно. То есть, если повторно переупаковывать файл программы UPX`ом, то код меняться не будет, все останется, как прежде?

Comment: Упаковка UPX'ом ничего не дает: 1) она действует только во время анализа файловой системы, 2) код UPX'а открыт и, полагаю, упакованные файлы прозрачны для антивирусов (хотя это надо перепроверить).

Comment: А как же скрыться от антивирусного ока?

Comment: @Asen Обычно для этого просто достаточно быть умнее, чем `1.5 * среднего работника` антивирусной компании.